# Number of vertices in each partition in graphs at GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-graphx

How can you count how many vertices are they in each partition in a graph?

While in RDD spark has the

> .mapPartition,

the graphs in GraphX doesn't have similar *.mapPartitionVertices*, so you can't count how many elements are they in the partition.

I was wondering if you have a better way to do it than getting the vertices, and then check it manually:

> graph.vertices.mapPartitions

Answer (score 2):

The `VertexRDD` class doesn't have transformation method to operate on partitions, however you can apply `map` transformation to get `RDD` object then count number of records per partition. The map transformation will not alter elements and number of elements per partition.

**E.g.**

```
val countRDD = graph.vertices.map{ case (id, attr) => (id, attr) }
.mapPartitionsWithIndex{case (i,rows) => Iterator((i,rows.size))}

countRDD.collect()
```